# random.shuffle() not working for number guessing game

Tags: python, random, numbers, generator, python-3.4

Im making a text based adventure game but at one point I want the user to be stuck typing numbers endlessly. I'm very new and python so the simpler the better but here's what i've got so far anyway.

Here is the code

```
import os
import sys
import string

import time
import random
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' , '9']

print("Welcome to My Text Adventure Game: Dumb Edition")
print ("You (yes YOU) awake in an E-M-P-T-Y room.")
print ("It's very chilly willy and someone is drawing on the walls")
print (" Do you exit the room via the door that is obviously the right way (1)")
print ("what do you do?")
time.sleep(1)
print("Wait!")
print("You can't be trusted to not get this wrong")
print("I'll do it")
print("1")
time.sleep(1)
print("Erm...It should be going..")
print("Meh I'll just make something up! Two seconds..")
time.sleep(3)
print ("Ok.. I've got it! You'll just press buttons and it will be fun!")
print ("Or else..")
print ("Here we go...")
time.sleep(1)
print ("Please enter the following")
while True:
        rng_number = random.shuffle(numbers)
        print (rng_number)
        user_input = input("Go on, type it in!")
        if user_input == rng_number:
                print("Good job again!")
        else:
                print("Try again...Moron")
```

Here is what happens when I run the code

```
Welcome to My Text Adventure Game: Dumb Edition
You (yes YOU) awake in an E-M-P-T-Y room.
It's very chilly willy and someone is drawing on the walls
 Do you exit the room via the door that is obviously the right way?(1)
what do you do?
Wait!
You can't be trusted to not get this wrong
I'll do it
1
Erm...It should be going..
Meh I'll just make something up! Two seconds..
Ok.. I've got it! You'll just press buttons and it will be fun!
Or else..
Here we go...
Please enter the following
None
Go on, type it in!None
Try again...Moron
None
Go on, type it in!
```

Comment: please add your code here.

Comment: First of all please paste you code as a code not as image. `random.shuffle(x[, random]) Shuffle the sequence x in place` [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.shuffle)
In other words when you call `rng_number=random.shuffle(numbers)` it just shuffle numbers array and assign `None` to `rng_number` (`random.shuffle()` returns None). And  `input` read text input from user you should convert it to int.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've changed the input to int(input("Go on, type it in!")) but I'm still getting none instead of a number.

Comment: @TheFlyingScotsman and you will - as Alex has pointed out - shuffle returns `None` - try taking a look at `random.choice` instead

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the issue with your program is that `random.shuffle()` does not assign a number to `rng_number`. In order to assign a value from `numbers` to `rng_number`, you must use `random.choice()` instead ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html#random.choice)).

```
import random
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8' , '9']

while True:
    rng_number = random.choice(numbers)
    print (rng_number)
    user_input = input("Go on, type it in!")
    if user_input == rng_number:
        print("Good job again!")
    else:
        print("Try again...Moron")
```